# Woocommerce ajax search can't work on mobile

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, search

It's wired my ajax search code can work on the desktop, but in the mobile browser, the ajax search doesn't have any responses. I don't know how to get the trick.

html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search product ... "name="keyword" id="keyword" onkeyup="fetch()"></input>

<div id="fetched_data">Search results will appear here</div>
```

and following I put into the function.php

```
// Search box and ajax search
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_fetch' );

function ajax_fetch() { 
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function fetch() { 
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword:jQuery('#keyword').val() },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#fetched_data').html( data );
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
    <?php 
}
```

```
// the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){
    if ($_POST['pcat']) {
        $product_cat_id = array(esc_attr( $_POST['pcat'] ));
    }else {
        $terms = get_terms( 'product_cat' ); 
        $product_cat_id = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'term_id' );
    }
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 
        array( 
            'posts_per_page' => -1, 
            's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 
            'post_type' => array('product'),
            
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
                    'field'     => 'term_id',
                    'terms'     => $product_cat_id,
                    'operator'  => 'IN',
                )
           )
        ) 
    );
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        echo '<ul>';
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); ?>

            <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><span><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail')?></span><?php the_title();?></a></li>

        <?php endwhile;
       echo '</ul>';
        wp_reset_postdata();  
    endif;

    die();
}
```

Comment: `fetch` is already a function in JavaScript. You should give your function a unique name (I don't know if this is your problem, but it's where I'd start).

Comment: Is the javascript present on the source code of mobile? Type view-source: before the url on mobile if javascript is missing clear your site/browser caches.